# use c++ method in c program

Tags: c++, c, openwrt, gloox

I want to use C++ library gloox in my C code (easycwmp package for openwrt).

I compile with openwrt toolschain the gloox as package:

here is the cpp file gloox.cpp :

```
#include "gloox.h" 
namespace gloox 
{
  const std::string XMPP_STREAM_VERSION_MAJOR = "1";
  const std::string XMPP_STREAM_VERSION_MINOR = "0";
  const std::string GLOOX_VERSION           = "1.0.11";
  const std::string GLOOX_CAPS_NODE         = "http://camaya.net/gloox";
}
extern "C" const char* gloox_version()
{
  return gloox::GLOOX_VERSION.c_str();
}
```

the header file gloox.h :

```
#ifndef GLOOX_H__
#define GLOOX_H__

#include "macros.h"


extern "C" //--> error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant 
{
  GLOOX_API const char* gloox_version();
}

#endif // GLOOX_H__
```

the compilation of gloox package is OK 
when I include gloox.h in my C code of easycwmp package I get this error :

staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/include/gloox.h:12:8: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant !!

I compile libgloox with command :

```
make package/libgloox/compile
```

and then I compile easycwmp package with cmd :

```
make package/easycwmp/compile
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you show us `macros.h` ?

Comment: From looking at it, it seems like you need to wrap the entire gloox library in a C wrapper if you want to use it. I think it's a better idea to write "C-like" C++ than to do all the work needed to wrap it.

Answer (score 2):

extern "C" is a C++ construct, so you need to guard your header so it can be used from both C and C++ code like so:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" 
    {
#endif

GLOOX_API const char* gloox_version();

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

Also note that you need to link using a C++ frontend, even if all your code is C, so use g++ for linking instead of gcc.

Comment: when compile main.c I got error undefined reference to `gloox_version'

Comment: @Anis_Stack Then you did something wrong. Tell us what you did: Which commands are you running. How did you create your library. How did you link in that library.

Comment: I compile the goolx library with openwrt toolschain "toolchain-i386_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2" and with "--mode=link i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc-g++" . After compilation, I include the gloox.h in my C program

Comment: @Anis_Stack You have to copy/paste the commands you are running to compile and link your program, and the output you get, otherwise we can only guess as to what you are actually doing. e.g. noone else knows if you have actually linked to the gloox library, or if you typed something wrong when you're trying to link to the gloox library - or anything else that might be wrong. (Keep in mind that you need to link to the library you want to use in addition to including any header files from that library)

Comment: I use openwrt toolschain, so to compile package the command is "make package/libgloox/compile V=s" !

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `extern "C"` in C code (including in a .h file that's used from a .c file), only in C++ code.

You need to surround it with `#ifdef __cplusplus` so it's only active when you `#include` it from a .cpp file, not a .c file.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
GLOOX_API const char* gloox_version();
```

Comment: when compile main.c I got error undefined reference to `gloox_version'